# the correct way to use pcap_next_ex or pcap_next (libpcap)

Tags: libpcap

I saw this kind of code used in a project:

```
while (1)
{
  l_numPkts = pcap_next_ex( m_pcapHandle, &header, &pkt_data);
  //do something
  memcpy(dst,pkt_data,size);    
}
```

after the pcap_next_ex return,the packet status will be set TP_STATUS_KERNEL,which means the buf was return to kernel.
code:

```
 /* next packet */
 switch (handle->md.tp_version) {
  case TPACKET_V1:
  h.h1->tp_status = TP_STATUS_KERNEL;
..
```

in some high speed environment,will it get a memory problem?

and what is the correct way to use pcap_next / pcap_next_ex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I freezed on this problem in python with [winpcapy](http://code.google.com/p/winpcapy/) (1.9.2009) and WinPcap 4.1.0.2001.

I solved it simply by creating copy of packet data array (as suggested by memcpy mentioned in question).

`pkt_data = pkt_data[:header.contents.len]`

Not sure if it's correct but works for me at the moment.

And based on answer at [winpcap papermail](http://www.winpcap.org/pipermail/winpcap-users/2008-August/002700.html) this what pkt_data references to should persist until next call of pcap_next_ex (or other dispatch method). If i got it right, because it uses one buffer for more/all packets and so it can be reused for other/last packets?

Q.

Answer (score -1):

```
char errbuff[10000];
pcap_t * handler = pcap_open_offline(argv[1], errbuff);
struct pcap_pkthdr *header;
u_char  *packet;
while (pcap_next_ex(handler, &header, &packet) >= 0)
{
    printf("len %d:\n",header->len);
     ... YOUR CODE


}
```